# Python memory allocation with pandas and pickle

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am running a python script which can be roughly summed (semi-psuedo-coded) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file,'r') as fin:
        data = fin.readlines()
    data_str = '[' + ','.join(x.strip() for x in data) + ']'
    df = pd.read_json(data_str)
    df.to_pickle('%s.pickle' % json_file)
    del df, data, data_str
```

The process works iteratively creating data frames, saving them each to a unique file. However, my memory seems to get used up during the process, as if `del df, data, data_str` does not free up memory (originally, I did not include the `del` statement in the code, but I hoped that adding it would resolve the issue -- it did not). During each iteration, approximately the same amount of data is being read into the data frame, approximately 3% of my available memory; as the process iterates, each iteration a there is a reported 3% bump in `%MEM` (from `ps u | grep [p]ython` in my terminal), and eventually my memory is swamped and the process is killed. My question is how should I change my code/approach so that at each iteration, the memory from the previous iteration is freed?

To note, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.2 via Anaconda.

Thanks in advance for your direction.

Comment: You are right, you don't need to `del` the variables in the `for` loop because the old object's ref count is decremented each time the variables rebind in the loop. They hang around after the `for` completes but if this is in a function, that reference goes away too. The only wild guess I have is that `clean_json_to_str` could do something bad like keep a background reference to the object.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer @tdelaney. I've updated my question to be more explicit with the `clean_json_to_str` step and be honest about everything I threw into the `del` call (albeit, as you mentioned, this shouldn't be the issue).

Comment: I created a version of your code that i could test [here](http://pastebin.com/Xg25HZji) and it showed no strange memory consumption. You are likely to get a few bumps because the underlying heap expands and has empty available space in the first few iterations. But that evens out and for me, there was no memory increase.

Comment: Why do you want to pickle a JSON based dataframe? Pickling in general is not memory efficient, and kind of redundant for JSON based objects. See https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/python-memory-management-part-ii/ for the details of pickling. I would just save the cleaned JSON in a different text file and use the `json` module to read it when needed.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for your code and looking into this. It is really strange on my end and behaving in a way I find at odds with your outcome.

Comment: @Munir This is just one step in many, so while the "why do this" here might not be clear, it is something that I would like to be able to do. At that, even if it's a wasted effort, the error is not in line with what I thought would happen and so exploring this will still (hopefully) prove fruitful for me.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 2):

In python automatic garbage collection deallocates the variable (pandas DataFrame are also just another object in terms of python). There are different garbage collection strategies that can be tweaked (requires significant learning).

You can manually trigger the garbage collection using

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

But frequent calls to garbage collection is discouraged as it is a costly operation and may affect performance.

[Reference](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection)

Comment: garbage collection is only needed when simple object reference counting isn't enough to determine whether deletion is needed (circular references for example). It isn't needed in OP's case and won't solve the problem.